# Can I dynamically do a bulk update on a JSON field while referencing a model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am caching some data on my model and this is essentially what I'd like to achieve.

```
Person.objects.all().update(my_links={first_link='https://first_url/{id}'.format(id=F('id'))})
```

The result I get is:

```
{ "first_link": "https://first_url/F(id)" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use format because the way it's evaluated will cast everything as a string before it's passed to the ORM as you can see.

However I think using basic concatenation with `Value` should work:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value

Person.objects.all().update(my_links={'first_link': Value('https://first_url/') + F('id')})
```

Comment: I get an exception with that :( `Object of type CombinedExpression is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Maybe try: `Person.objects.all().update(my_links__first_link=Value('https://first_url/') + F('id'))`. Just a guess.

Comment: Ah that was a good attempt but unfortunately it does not work.  I know querying works for that though so I see why you gave it a shot.  I see there's a ticket for that https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29112

Comment: I think you'll have to do it with RawSQL (using jsonb_set function if you're using postgresql) or write an ORM funciton. Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42023669/1529346

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that.